# div css3 name question

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML which I'm working on:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
      <title>templates</title>
      <meta name="description" content="" />
      <meta name="author" content="wobben" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href=styles.css"> 
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="container">
       <header>
           <img src="http://www.tamarawobben.nl/images/3.jpg" alt="" width="750" height="225" />
       </header>
       <nav>
           <p><a href="/">Home</a></p>
           <p><a href="/contact">Contact</a></p>
       </nav>
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Copyright  by wobben</p>
     </footer>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

In the old CSS, the name of the header would be `#header`. Is that still that way. I'm asking because he image is on another place then the old html4 code.

---

I did change everything but still no luck.

I have this as html :

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <title></title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="/js/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="container">
     <header>
        <img src="http://www.tamarawobben.nl/images/3.jpg" alt="" width="750" height="225" />
 </header>
```

And I have this in my css :

```
  header {display: block; height: 225px; width: 758px; margin: 0 1px 10px 1px; background: #fff;}
  #container {
width: 760px;
margin: 10px auto;
padding: 1px 0;
text-align: left;
background: #fff;
color: #303030;
   }
```

But still the image is on the left side instead of centered.

Can anyone help me once again.

Roelof

Comment: If you need to ask, don't use `<header>`. Get the basics of front-end work sorted out first before planning for stuff that hasn't yet arrived (like, any practical uses of `<header>` elements).

Comment: @Nicholas: Hasn't arrived yet? There has been support for `<header>` and HTML5 in general in major browsers for quite a while now. IE8 is the new IE6! Besides, you don't *have* to style them to take advantage of the supposed semantic benefits.

Comment: I know that the tags are arrived.

Comment: I use the html5 boilerplate but still I have no luck to make it work

Comment: As I said, no practical use for them has arrived. Sure, browsers style them, and some people are putting them in, but there are no consumers taking advantage of the "supposed semantic benefits". It's not arrived until it starts doing something useful.

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you need an html5 shim/shiv? You should also have some html5 in your reset.css or whichever one you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the new HTML5 tags while also supporting older browsers, you really need to be using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).  It will help your page handle the newer tags and degrade gracefully on browsers that don't support CSS3.

Read this article for a good explanation: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr/

To directly answer your question, use the syntax that Jason gave:

```
header { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<header>` like above and your want to **style** it, you should do the following in your stylesheet

```
header{
    display:block;
    //OTHER STYLES YOU WANT
}
```

as `header` is treated as an `inline` element in some browsers.

Also, all IEs below 9 do not render these elements in the DOM....so they won't show at all.

One way to get around this is to use a script `onload` to create these elements in the DOM.  Something like

```
var e = ("abbr,article,aside,audio,canvas,datalist,details, 
figure,footer,header,hgroup,mark,menu,meter,nav,output,
progress,section,time,video").split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    document.createElement(e[i]);
}
```

- *Line breaks in the array for SO formatting only*

Answer (score 0):

To clear out this mess, the era of header, nav, footer tag actually already has arrived. Every major browser (chrome, safari, firefox, opera) supports it so you can't say that it hasn't arrived. If you want to support the future, then use them. However if you have a client who's from the 90's then don't and save yourself some headache.